# O que é documento de visão?

Tags: terminologia, metodologia, metodologia-ágil

Gostaria de saber, o que é um documento de visão?

Obs.: Procurei na internet e acredito que as explicações que encontrei não foram o bastante para eu começar a entender. Isto, porque não me forneceram exemplos de documentos de visão e porque não me disseram porque o documento se chama de visão etc.

Comment: Documento de visão é uma nomenclatura do RUP :P se não me engano a analise é feita sob quatro visões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O documento de visão captura restrições de design e requisitos de alto nível para que o cliente possa compreender o sistema que será desenvolvido. Seu objetivo é fornecer uma visão ampla do produto que se pretende desenvolver, sem se aprofundar em detalhes técnicos.

Neste link da IBM tem um exemplo de um documento de visão: [Exemplo de documento de visão](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSWMEQ_3.0.1/com.ibm.rational.rrm.help.doc/topics/r_vision_doc.html).